# Google Desktop sidebar replacement?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, sidebar, google-desktop-search

I'm trying desperately to find a possible replacement to the dockable sidebar in Google Desktop.

I've fallen in love with having my widescreen-estate able to "HUD" me to things like my weather, news, mail, and even the random images.

Problem is that I want more than the Google Desktop sidebar wants to give (better placement of components, more than one bar, etc...).

I figure there has to be something out there like this (at least I really, ***REALLY*** hope there is).

I would figure someone like [StarDock](http://www.stardock.com) would have done this already (with their crazy desktops and all), but I just looked over their site and didn't see anything there.

Perhaps a freeware with a big community that has tons of plugins... please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use [Windows Sidebar](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Windows-Sidebar-and-gadgets-overview) that comes free with Windows Vista?

From the site:

> Windows Sidebar is a long, vertical
> bar that is displayed on the side of
> your desktop. It contains
> mini-programs called gadgets, which
> offer information at a glance and
> provide easy access to frequently used
> tools. For example, you can use
> gadgets to display a picture slide
> show, view continuously updated
> headlines, or look up contacts.

The Windows Sidebar has been [removed from Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-happened-to-Windows-Sidebar).

There's also [Desktop Sidebar](http://www.desktopsidebar.com/), which is freeware.

To run multiple instances of the Sidebar, follow these instructions:

From their [Desktop Sidebar FAQ](http://www.desktopsidebar.com/faq.html):

> Open up any simple text editor like
> notepad. Enter the lines below or copy
> and paste them.
>
> cd Program Files\desktop sidebar\
>
> dsidebar.exe -config "Desktop Sidebar 2"
>
> exit
>
> The "Desktop Sidebar 2" tells
> windows to run a instance of Desktop
> Sidebar with the name "Desktop Sidebar
> 2". This can be done as "Desktop
> Sidebar 3" or anything you like, just
> remeber that changing the name of it
> will get rid of all your settings for
> that instance, unless you rename it
> the same.
>
> Click file > Save As > Browse to the
> root of your C: Drive. > Enter
> Sidebar.bat as the Filename > Choose
> All Files as the File type > Click
> Save
>
> Locate the file and right click it >
> Chose Send To > Desktop (Create
> Shortcut). Now you can run the second
> instance of DS anytime you want to by
> clicking the shortcut.

Comment: Do either of these support multiple bars or more control over the positioning and the like?

Comment: Windows Sidebar, no-- I don't think so.  For Desktop Sidebar, yes-- according to their FAQ which I've updated in my answer.

Comment: This software (Desktop Sidebar) is ***exactly*** what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: note for people who are looking for a sidebar with integrated Google Calendar: doesn't exist for "Desktop Sidebar". There is a user-developed "list of events" extracting these from GCal, but nothing that looks like a real calendar, allowing to switch months or look up other activities than the ones of the next 7 days. :/